# How to tell what adb is parsing

Tags: adb

I am trying to get adb working on an aarch64 board. The actual binary runs, it just always shows that the devices are always empty.

I know for a fact the device is working because I have a second, statically linked adb binary from https://github.com/hduong85/arm_adb that works (but is too large for our specs). This binary needs zero config to detect the usb device. I could delete /etc/udev/rules.d and it would still find the device.

I got a much smaller one from https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/xenial/arm64/android-tools-adb

And it runs, but the devices are always empty.

I tried editing `/etc/udev/rules.d/50-android.rules`, `51-android.rules`, `70-android.rules`, `~/.android/adb_usb.ini`, you name it, nothing helps.

The problem is, I have no idea if adb is even using/parsing these sources of information. It never complains about anything. How can I tell?

And what's up with the android_usb gadget that I see some places where you set configs in /sys/class/android_usb? Our board is running linux 4.4 and does not have the android usb gadget driver. Why is adb so fragmented on how to config it?

Any debug tips welcome!

Comment: I just gave up and hacked around in hduong85/arm_adb Markefiles until I got it to dynamically link against libraries we already have (libcrypto, etc.)